# issue with iphone NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, google-api

I have an iphone application in which I want to draw the route between two locations on the map. The locations are refered  by their coordinates(latitude, longitude).

For loading the waypoints between those two locations I use a script that acces google maps, with this method:

```
function loadDirections(from, to, options) {
        gdir.load("from: " + from + " to: " + to, options);
    }
```

`from` should be of this form: `46.777248,23.59989` and `to` also like this: `44.437711,26.097367`.

In other words if I write this method like this:

```
   function loadDirections(from, to, options) {

        gdir.load("from:46.777248,23.59989 to:44.437711,26.097367 ", options);
    }
```

everything goes great.

Now, going into my iphone app....this is how I call this method:

[`directions loadWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint options:options];`

```
- (void)loadWithStartPoint:(NSString *)startPoint endPoint:(NSString *)endPoint options:(UICGDirectionsOptions *)options {
    [googleMapsAPI stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadDirections('%@', '%@', %@)", startPoint, endPoint, [options JSONRepresentation]]];
}
```

In other words, `startPoint` should contain the coordinates of the first location like this:

46.777248,23.59989  and `endPoint` should have the same form.

So in my iphone app I receive the latitude and longitude for the `startPoint` and also for the `endPoint` and in order to have them under the requested form I have this:

```
    NSString *startPoint;
        NSString *endPoint;

startPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];
endPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", partenaire_lat, partenaire_lng];
```

But when I call the javascript through this

```
options.travelMode = UICGTravelModeDriving;
    [directions loadWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint options:options];
```

the app blocks.I assume it doesn't like the way `startPoint` and `endPoint` are formatted.

IMPORTANT: When I call the above method with `null` values for `startPoint` and `endPoint` the app works.

Anyone has any idea?
I did my best to explain it very clearly!!!!!I'm here in case something is unclear!

Comment: What do you see if you log the string you send to `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString`?

Comment: In your endPoint, are partenaire_lat and partenaire_lng also strings? If not, the %@ should be %f

Comment: @adrin, have you found any solution? i am stucked on same point.

Comment: well, there is an accepted answer. i guess i used that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may solve your problem,

NSString *startPoint;
        NSString *endPoint;

startPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", latitudeString, longitudeString];
endPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@", partenaire_lat, partenaire_lng];

[startPoint retain];
[endPoint retain];

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are adding single quotes around the coordinates. These get preserved when you concatenate the strings in your function `loadDirections` (assuming that is a javascript function).

Also, you have a space after from: and to: in your `loadDirections`, don't know if that is important.

Try

```
- (void)loadWithStartPoint:(NSString *)startPoint endPoint:(NSString *)endPoint options:(UICGDirectionsOptions *)options {
    [googleMapsAPI stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadDirections(%@, %@, %@)", startPoint, endPoint, [options JSONRepresentation]]];
}
```